# How do I get YYYY-M-d hh:mm:ss as a datetime datatype?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, date, datetime

Currently I'm getting error due to datetime format and I want in this way YYYY-M-d hh:mm:ss as a datetime format for datetime datatype but I don't know how to get that. Can You please tell me how to do that?  I had a service and client developed in c#.net and both are connected with the database ms sql server and datetime is updated at runtime with current datetime.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where and why are you doing the string conversion? You shouldn't need to do it when you're talking to the database.

Comment: This website might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString,"YYYY-M-d HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Nope, `dateTimeString` is the first argument, not `format`.

Comment: Note that this won't handle any afternoon values. I suspect the OP *actually* wants `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` but just doesn't know it. `yyyy-M-d` is a very odd date format, and you should pretty much never use `hh` without `tt`.

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah, missed that. I've just copy pasted format (not proud of that) without checking it. Changed to `HH`. I'm also thinking it's desired format not `AM/PM`

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned MS Sql Server you can get current time in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS(24h)` format as:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 120)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLDateTimeFormats.aspx) is a list of all the datetime formats in SQL Server

As for your query the below query should work

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE(), 120)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Func<DateTime, string> GetTimeFormated = time => time.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm").Split(' ').ToArray().LastOrDefault();
```